# how to add new records to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a XAMPP MySQL database to add new records. I believe I did everything right but for some reason no new rows are being added to my database table. Can anyone look through the code and tell me what's wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("projects", $connect);
$button = $_POST['button'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$seatingplan = $_POST['seatingplan'];
$numberofseats = $_POST['numberofseats'];
$date= $_POST['date'];
$branch = $_POST['branch'];

if ($button)
{
if($username && $seatingplan && $numberofseats && $date &&$branch)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservations(Username, Seating plan, Number of seats, Date, Branch)VALUES('$username','$seatingplan','$numberofseats,'$date','$branch')");
}
else
echo"You did not fill in the fields";
}
?>
<html>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style codecademy.css">
<body background="http://hative.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/chinese-traditional-bamboo-background-template-4260.jpg">
 <h1 style="color:orange"> <b> <i> Reservation Form</i> </b> </h1>
<form action="reservation.php" method="POST">
<form>
<b style="color:orange; font-size:20px">Seating plan:<name="seatingplan"></b>
<select> Seating plan
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<b style="color:orange; font-size:20px">Number of seats: <input type="text" name="numberofseats"></b>
</form>
 <img src="plan.jpg"alt="plan" width="450" height="350">
<form><b style="color:orange; font-size:20px"> Pick the date :<name="date"> </b>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/Calendar.aspx"></script>
</form>
<form>
<b style="color:orange; font-size:20px">Restaurant branch:<name="branch"></b>
<select>Restaurant branch
  <option value="Saryarka Ave.">Saryarka Ave.</option>
  <option value="Zhubanov Str.">Zhubanov Str.</option>
</select>
</form>
<b style="color:orange; font-size:20px">Username:<input type="text" name="username"></b>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var json = '{"servers":{"server1":1,"server2":2},"slots":{"slotOne":1,"slotDual":0.5,"slotTripple":0.7,"slotMonstro":2.857142857142857},"rents":{"week":7,"day":1,"oneYear":365,"forewer":null}}'; //this string is beckoming from the server
    data = JSON.parse(json);    
}
function recalc() {
    var server = document.getElementById('server').value;
    var slot = document.getElementById('slot').value;
    var rent = document.getElementById('rent').value;
    var formul9;
    try {
    formul9 = (data.servers[server]+data.slots[slot])*data.rents[rent];
    } catch (e) { }
    if(isNaN(formul9)) formul9 = +Infinity;
    formul9 = parseFloat(formul9).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = formul9.toString();
};

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate your column names if there are `spaces` in the column names using the character `

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservations(`Username`, `Seating plan`, `Number of seats`, `Date`, `Branch`) VALUES('$username','$seatingplan','$numberofseats,'$date','$branch')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Such things you have to keep in mind like `db field_name` should not have a space, secondly you have not checked that button and values are `set` or not and last thing is use `concatenation` in your `query`, or replace below line into your code

```
<?php
if(isset($button))
{
  if(isset($username && $seatingplan && $numberofseats && $date &&$branch))
  {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservations (`Username`,`Seating plan`,`Number of seats`,`Date`,`Branch`)VALUES('".$username."','".$seatingplan."','".$numberofseats."','".$date."','".$branch."')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think query error try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservations(`Username`, `Seating plan`, `Number of seats`, `Date`, `Branch`) VALUES('".$username."','".$seatingplan."','".$numberofseats."','".$date."','".$branch."')");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not add space in column name

**ERROR**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservations(Username, Seating plan, Number of seats, Date, Branch)VALUES('$username','$seatingplan','$numberofseats,'$date','$branch')");
```

Try below code after correcting colunm name.You can use `_` instead of space in column name.

**PHP**

```
   <?php
        error_reporting(0);
        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db("projects", $connect);
        $button = $_POST['button'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $seatingplan = $_POST['seatingplan'];
        $numberofseats = $_POST['numberofseats'];
        $date= $_POST['date'];
        $branch = $_POST['branch'];

    if ($button)
    {
        if($username && $seatingplan && $numberofseats && $date &&$branch)
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservations(Username, Seating_plan, Number_of_seats, Date, Branch)VALUES('$username','$seatingplan','$numberofseats,'$date','$branch')");
        }
    else
        echo"You did not fill in the fields";
    }
    ?>
```